# SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns child items not loaded

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have following lists

1. Project (Title, Description, ect)
2. Release (Title, ReleaseID, ProjectID, etc) ProjectID is a lookup of Project:Title
3. Task (TaskID, project, release) Project is a Lookup of Project:Title and release is a lookup of Release:ReleaseID

In the NewForm.aspx of Task List I have added the following script.

```
    <script language="javascript" src="/sites/PM/SiteAssets/Jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script language="javascript" src="/sites/PM/SiteAssets/Jquery/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {


  $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "Release",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "ProjectID",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "ReleaseID",
    parentColumn: "Project",
    childColumn: "Release",
   debug: true
  });
});
</script>
```

The Project Dropdown (Parent) gets populated but the release dropdown (Child) doesn't.

What could be the cause. Thanks in advance.

**Update** : I checked with firebug. Upon selection of the parent, a response returns with the right ItemCount, but they are not loaded to the child dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my jquery library was too old. I added jquery-3.1.1.js library, and now it work. My final scripts looks like

```
    <script language="javascript" src="/sites/PM/SiteAssets/Jquery/jquery-3.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="/sites/PM/SiteAssets/Jquery/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {


      $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "Release",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "ProjectID",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "ReleaseID",
        parentColumn: "Project",
        childColumn: "Release",
        matchOnId: true,
        debug: true
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per SPServices Cascade documentation,

> **parentColumn** The DisplayName of the parent column in the form
>
> **childColumn** The DisplayName of the child column in the form

So on your task form you have parent column as : **p**roject (not "**P**roject"), child column as "**r**elease (not "**R**elease")

Comment: I changed the parentColumn: "project", childColumn: "release". But then all the child items got loaded. I'll update the question, because in firebug, i get a response with original code.

Comment: Set matchOnId and debug to true. Refer this for more information https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: That didn't work either.